# Facebook iOS SDK : Login with Facebook failed

Tags: ios, facebook

after I read few references on the internet, I decided to use `Facebook SDK for iOS` instead of `XCode Social Framework`.

Because what I need on my app is **'login with facebook'** session and I'm following its sample code named SessionLoginSample under Sample folder but it doesn't work when I put on my code. These code was build successfully on iPad simulator but when I click the button, nothing happen.

Could you please show me where did I miss here... thank you...

I have this **AppDelegate.h** :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;

@end
```

and here's **my AppDelegate.m** :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize session = _session;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:self.session];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.session close];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:self.session];
}

#pragma mark Template generated code

@end
```

my **ViewController.h** :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fieldPassword;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLogin;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelOutput;

- (IBAction)buttonRegister;
- (IBAction)buttonLogin;
- (IBAction)loginFacebook;
- (IBAction)loginTwitter;

@end
```

my **ViewController.m** :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController* navController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString *)msg
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                      message:msg
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}

- (IBAction)loginFacebook {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    } else {
        if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
            appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        }

        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
            [self alertWithTitle:(@"FB Login") andMessage:(@"It works!!")];
        }];
    } }
}
@end
```

UPDATE : I have add FacebookSDK.framework under Framework folder on my project, also modified the plist file based on [this introduction](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/851559_148282688685691_1981352615_n.png) too :

Comment: check in the device whether you have  granted the permission to use the application you are working on and whether you have already signed up with the  facebook application on the device.....check both the steps and then run the app on device.i think then it would shoe the login page for facebook login.

Comment: I have install / run this app on my iPad so I believe my device already have permission. I also have created an app on my Facebook account. And since it's new app and because the button is not working, I haven't authorise on my device.

Comment: Hoping you have followed all steps as given provided in the sample app.you can check the permissions granted to use facebook settings for the app you are working on in the ipad by goin to settings. I had faced the same issue and it was this reason only which was doing nothing on tap of facebook button.Please check that first.in the meanwhile i would provide you with some links i have.

Comment: check out his link and go through all the answers once -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159965/com-facebook-sdk-error-2-on-ios  .. may be it can be of help to you.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view you are mission a call like -setActiveSession in

```
if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) 
{
   appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
   [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];
}
```

I had the same problem integrating iOS Facebook sdk 3.5 a month ago, And I found out that your current active session doesn't set automatically. So I have this call wherever there is a chance of getting a different session instance.

Also,

inside

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
   {
      [FBAppEvents activateApp];
      [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:self.session];
   }
```

instead of self.session, you should use FBSession.activeSession just to ensure that the FBAppCall gets the same instance of FBSession, for which it has got the result.

Hope that helps.