# iOS App development with Facebook API bundle ID error message

Tags: xcode, facebook-graph-api, bundle-identifier

I'm developing an iOS App with Facebook API. The app was working fine but I started to get the below error;

"There was an error:fbplatse:{"message": "No Bundle ID has been set on the server" }.     Please tap Cancel to return to APPNAME and try again."

Actually I don't think I made any changes to the server. Can you please help me to fix this?

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem.

1. add your app's bundle ID into the 'Native iOS App' tab under 'developers.facebook.com/apps'
2. Your app's bundle ID should be the same with the one above (Facebook developer page)
3. After I added up my bundle ID, I started to receive 'com.facebook.sdk error code=2' messages. It is good to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159965/com-facebook-sdk-error-2-on-ios) which explains everything step by step about the error code and how to get rid of it.
4. So, in my specific situation following worked; Device's Settings => Facebook and then log in with the credentials.

I spent too much time on that but now it works!

Comment: This wasn't my exact problem, but it got me to look through all the settings on developers.facebook.com/apps. The facebook login integration worked for me but not my friends login. It needs to be set public under the "Status & Review", since it was my facebook dev account otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has updated it's documentation since this post in 2013. They have provided a screenshot showing where to get the bundle identifier. It's not the code with the variable in it from the Info.plist in Supporting Files directory. Rather, tap on the project file in Xcode (the topmost file in the directory) and see General tab (which is open by default).

I've attached a screen grab. Hopefully this helps someone.

[image: locate your Bundle Identifier to submit to Facebook]